# vscode extensions' information not loading

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everything is working properly except that when I open the extensions tab and click on any extension, this is what I get `↓↓↓`
I also can't install or update any extensions, I get an error `Failed to update/Install with CTA "Download Manually"` as shown in the image in the link below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KHr1.png)

Update: Just installed a vpn and when I opened vscode again, extensions loaded properly and the problem has been fixed.

```
VSCode Version: 1.38.1
OS: Windows 10
```

Comment: I changed my network and got worked

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was just configuring my network settings to use Google DNS.